# Editor not selecting both sides of cylinder

Tags: modeling, vertices

[image]

I selected it from the side using B, but when I ctrl + R it does not go to do the other side.

Comment: It looks like those faces aren't connected, or there's an ngon in between so loop cut doesn't know how to proceed.

Comment: You might have to hide the reference and send a couple more angles.